# idiomatic way to share styles in styled-components?

Tags: javascript, styled-components, jss

trying to port some code from jss to styled-components,
jss code looks something like:

```
//...
const styles = {
  myStyles: {
    color: 'green'
  }
}

const {classes} = jss.createStyleSheet(styles).attach()

export default function(props) {
  return (
     <div>
       <Widget1 className={classes.myStyles}/>
       <Widget2 className={classes.myStyles}/>
     </div>
  )
}
```

my question is what would be the idiomatic way to accomplish this sharing of the same styles across multiple components?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can either share actual CSS strings or share `styled-components` components:

- Share CSS strings:

```js
import {css} from 'styled-components'
const sharedStyle = css`
  color: green
`

// then later

const ComponentOne = styled.div`
  ${sharedStyle}
  /* some non-shared styles */
`
const ComponentTwo = styled.div`
  ${sharedStyle}
  /* some non-shared styles */
`
```

- Share actual `styled-components`:

```js
const Shared = styled.div`
  color: green;
`

// ... then later

const ComponentOne = styled(Shared)`
  /* some non-shared styles */
`
const ComponentTwo = styled(Shared)`
  /* some non-shared styles */
`
```

Update: Based on questions in the comments, I created an example to show that passing props to styled-components's `css` function works the same way as passing props to the components themselves: https://codesandbox.io/s/2488xq91qj?fontsize=14. The official recommendation from `styled-components` is to always wrap strings you will pass to `styled-components` in the `css` tag function. In this example, the `Test` component receives it background and foreground colors through passed-in props embedded in the `cssString` variable created by invoking the `css` function.

Comment: thanks @huy, that's kind of what i could gather, but just wanted to verify from someone with more experience. seems to be a little more verbose than a solution that hands out generated classes in that it requires extra lines to define styled components, but i guess they don't call it styled *components* for nuthin :)

Comment: this is great, but do you know how to pass props to `css`?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald you can create a function that accepts props and returns the `css`. styled-components will pass them automatically

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I create an example to show that passing props to `styled-components`'s `css` function works the same way as passing props to the components themselves: https://codesandbox.io/s/2488xq91qj?fontsize=14. In the example, the `Test` component receives it background and foreground colors through passed-in props embedded in the `cssString` variable created by invoking the `css` function.

Comment: You can also create a new component with the same css rules as another component but changing the html tag simply by using [withComponent](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#withcomponent). Quick example: `const PrimaryLink = PrimaryButton.withComponent('a');`

Comment: What about the concept of a "baseStyle" and an extended variant? For example, I want a button to have a gray / super basic style, and then have a primary variant in dark blue.

Answer (score 36):

In addition to the posted answer, you can also create a function that accepts `props` / `theme` and returns the ``` css`` ```.

`styled-components` will check the type of the value provided eg: `${shared}` and if its a `function` it will invoke it with the relevant `props` / `theme`.

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';

const shared = ({theme, myProp}) => css`
  color: ${theme.color};
`

/* ------------   */

const Component1 = styled.div`
  ${shared};
  /* more styles ... */
`
const Component2 = styled.div`
  ${shared};
  /* more styles ... */
`
```

Comment: its unnecessary to create this extra function, `shared` could just be its css. types are even propagated through although not using a wrapping function or explicitly setting the types on the components under

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the 2 answers above, you can also share style between tags as such:

```
const MyText = styled.div`
  color: orange;
`

const MyLink = MyText.withComponent("a")
```