# Styled Components - two different elements with the same styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `Button` component (in React) which can either be a `button` or an `a` element, depending on if a `href` prop is passed to the component. Something similar to below:

```
const Button = ({ children, href, onClick }) => {
    if(href) {
        return <a href={href} onClick={onClick}>{children}</a>;
    }

    return <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
};
```

I previously used Sass to style these components, but am now attempting to move over to `styled-components`. However, I have come across an issue where these two elements require the same styles, but the syntax of `styled-components` would require me to create to separate variables - `styled.button` and `styled.a`, with duplicated styles for each.

I was wondering if there was a way of dynamically changing the element used in `styled-components`, maybe based on props in the same way one can change individual CSS properties? I have attempted something along the lines of:

```
const StyledButton = styled((props) => props.href ? 'a' : 'button')`
    ...
`;
```

but no luck so far. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Create generic styles that you can reuse

You can extract and pass styles as string args to a styled component.

```
const buttonStyles = `
color: red;
...
`

const StyledA = styled.a(buttonStyles);
const StyledButton = styled.button(buttonStyles);
```

## If you need some exceptions

```
import styled, { css } from ‘styled-components’;

const baseInputStyles = css`
  padding: 0.5em;
`;

const StyledA = styled.a`
  ${baseInputStyles}
`;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  ${baseInputStyles}
  /* make changes as needed*/
`;
```

Comment: How can u get props in the mass style block?

Comment: @MoteZart https://stackoverflow.com/a/49622151/2590119 has the solution

Answer (score 0):

I tried Joe Lloyd's answer but it didn't work because the function `styled.xxx()` takes one parameter of type `templateStringsArray` instead of `template String`:

```
const buttonStyles = [
`
color: red;
...
`
]

const StyledA = styled.a(buttonStyles);
const StyledButton = styled.button(buttonStyles);
```

Comment: If you use `css\`\`` as mentioned in Joe's answer, it will take care of this for you. That answer does not show a raw template string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`css` helper](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) is only justified when interpolating a function, not a string.
In your case, it is more reasonable to use the [polymorphic props `as`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop):

```
const Title = styled.h1`
      ...
    `;

    return (
      <Title>Some title</Title>
      <Title as='h2'>Some another title</Title>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the other answers, you can create generic styles for this component, but from v4+, you can also use the `as` property to make a single component polymorphic.  (See [polymorphic prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) in Styled's documentation).

An example of this:

```js
const SomeButton = styled.button`
  border: red 1px solid;
`

function UsingSomeButtonAsALink(href) {
  return <SomeButton as={'a'} href={href}>Text</SomeButton>
}
```

In older versions of Styled, there was a similar polymorphic ability via the `.withComponent` API, but this was deprecated in v4 and removed completely in v6. The documentation no longer describes how to use this API.