# How can I apply the same styled components pattern to multiple svg components which already exist?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I've already seen how the same styles can be used for multiple components (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618997/idiomatic-way-to-share-styles-in-styled-components)) by making one component based on a previously made one, but that same logic doesn't seem to fit my case.

I imported my svg like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as UpsetEmoticon } from '../images/upset-emoticon.svg';
```

and used styled components to change the hover color like this:

```
const UpsetEmoticonStyled = styled(UpsetEmoticon)`
    & path {
        fill: white;
    }
    &:hover {
        & path {
            fill: gray;
        }
    }
`;
```

I want to apply this same styling to multiple svgs that I'm importing the same way. I could just repeat the code multiple times, switching out the SVG taken in styled() but if there is a way that's more concise I'd prefer that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to tackle this.

1. If they are in the same hierarchy, you can lift the styles to a common ancestor

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  svg {
    & path {
      fill: white;
    }
    &:hover {
      & path {
        fill: gray;
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <IconA />
      <IconB />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

2. Use styled-component's [`as`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) prop

```js
const StyledIcon = styled.svg`
    & path {
      fill: blue;
    }

    &:hover {
      & path {
        fill: gray;
      }
    }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledIcon as={IconA} />
      <StyledIcon as={IconB} />
    </div>
  );
}
```